# Create a csv from xml using php

Tags: php, xml-parsing, export-to-csv

I have an xml file and I wish to convert it to csv file. My xml file is a list of product with Product number and two types of attributes

1. `attrtype=ProductattributeTypeTechData`
2. `attrtype=ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply`

I managed to get all the `TypeTechData` attributes because its supposed to be all together in one file, but I am not able to figure out how to do the `TypeScopeSupply`. Here is the XML file

```
<PRV proid="96801" id="96802" name="1.601-555.0  K 2.080">
<PRODUCT_NUMBER>16015550</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
<COLL languagespecific="" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeTechData" ProdID="96802"     name="SPANNUNG_COLL" product_number="16015550" dictionary_entry="Voltage" dict_id="1775">
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeTechData" datatype="N" ProdID="96802"   name="SPANNUNG_VON" product_number="16015550">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="V" unit_id="3209" vo="" vo_id="">220</VALUE>
</PRAT>
</COLL>
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="F" ProdID="96802" name="INTEGRIERTER_FEINWASSERFILTER" product_number="16015550" dictionary_entry="Integrated fine mesh water filter" dict_id="2258">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="" unit_id="-1" vo="" vo_id="">1</VALUE>
</PRAT>
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="F" ProdID="96802" name="ADAPTER_GARTENSCHLAUCHANSCHLUSS_A3_4" product_number="16015550" dictionary_entry="Garden hose adapter A3/4&quot;" dict_id="2113">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="" unit_id="-1" vo="" vo_id="">1</VALUE>
</PRAT>
<COLL languagespecific="" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" ProdID="96802" name="QUICK_CONNECT_DUESEN_COLL" product_number="16015550" dictionary_entry="Kärcher Quick Connect standard nozzles" dict_id="44501">
<PRAT languagespecific="" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="F" ProdID="96802" name="QUCK_CONNECT_DUESEN_0" product_number="16015550"/>
</COLL>
</PRV>
<PRV proid="188613" id="422136" name="1.602-103.0  K 2.090">
<PRODUCT_NUMBER>16021030</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
<COLL languagespecific="" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeTechData" ProdID="422136" name="SPANNUNG_COLL" product_number="16021030" dictionary_entry="Voltage" dict_id="1775">
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeTechData" datatype="N" ProdID="422136" name="SPANNUNG_VON" product_number="16021030">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="V" unit_id="3209" vo="" vo_id="">220</VALUE>
</PRAT>
</COLL>
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="F" ProdID="422136" name="INTEGRIERTER_FEINWASSERFILTER" product_number="16021030" dictionary_entry="Integrated fine mesh water filter" dict_id="2258">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="" unit_id="-1" vo="" vo_id="">1</VALUE>
</PRAT>
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="F" ProdID="422136" name="ADAPTER_GARTENSCHLAUCHANSCHLUSS_A3_4" product_number="16021030" dictionary_entry="Garden hose adapter A3/4&quot;" dict_id="2113">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="" unit_id="-1" vo="" vo_id="">1</VALUE>
</PRAT>
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="F" ProdID="422136" name="HOCHDRUCKPISTOLE" product_number="16021030" dictionary_entry="High-pressure gun" dict_id="2173">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="" unit_id="-1" vo="" vo_id="">1</VALUE>
</PRAT>
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="S" ProdID="422136" name="REINIGUNGSMITTELSCHLAUCH" product_number="16021030" dictionary_entry="Cleaning agent hose" dict_id="2344">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="" unit_id="-1" vo="" vo_id="">With filter</VALUE>
</PRAT>
<PRAT languagespecific="0" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="F" ProdID="422136" name="EIN_FACH_STRAHLROHR" product_number="16021030" dictionary_entry="Single spray lance" dict_id="2247">
<VALUE nr="1" unit="" unit_id="-1" vo="" vo_id="">1</VALUE>
</PRAT>
<COLL languagespecific="" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" ProdID="422136" name="QUICK_CONNECT_DUESEN_COLL" product_number="16021030" dictionary_entry="Kärcher Quick Connect standard nozzles" dict_id="44501">
<PRAT languagespecific="" attrtype="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply" datatype="F" ProdID="422136" name="QUCK_CONNECT_DUESEN_0" product_number="16021030"/>
</COLL>
</PRV>
```

What I really want is to save each product in a separate csv named by product ID
Where only the data for `TypeScopeSupply` is stored if it has any value in it and have header as `dictionaryentry` for only those attributes. As there are some `TypeScopeSupply` which do not have any Values in it or say empty. I do not want these empty attributes to be echoed.

Other thing to note is values for `TypeScopeSupply` maybe as `COLL-PRAT-VALUE` or just `PRAT-VALUE`.
Even if I get an idea of how to do it I would appreciate. I purposely put a bigger xml file here to show variety in product attributes. Different products have different types of attributes.

```
<?php
$productfile = "Internet.xml";

//Build Product List
if (!$xml = simplexml_load_file($productfile)) {
echo "Unable to load XML file";
} else {
echo "<span style='white-space: nowrap'>";
$products = $xml->xpath('//PRV');
//Table Header
foreach ($products as $product) {
foreach ($product->COLL as $COLL) {
    foreach ($COLL->PRAT as $PRAT){
        if($COLL['attrtype']=="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply"){
        $headerarray[] =  $COLL['dictionary_entry'];
        }
    };
    };
foreach ($product->PRAT as $PRAT) {
    if($PRAT['attrtype']=="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply"){
    $headerarray[] =  $PRAT['dictionary_entry'];
    }
};
};
echo "ID,";

$headerarray = array_values(array_unique($headerarray));
//Build Seperate header array for woocommerce display
$header = implode($headerarray,"|");
$header = str_replace(",","",$header);
$header = explode("|",$header);
echo implode(",",$header);
echo "<br>";

//Build Stats Array
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo($product->PRODUCT_NUMBER);
    echo ",";
    foreach ($product->COLL as $COLL) {
        if($COLL['attrtype']=="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply"){
        $name = $COLL['dictionary_entry'];
        $unit = "";
        unset($values);
        foreach ($COLL->PRAT as $PRAT){
            foreach ($PRAT->VALUE as $VALUE) {
                $values[] = (string)$VALUE . $VALUE['unit'];
                };
            };
        $statsarray[(string)$name] = implode(array_filter($values),"|");
        }
    };
    foreach ($product->PRAT as $PRAT) {
        if($PRAT['attrtype']=="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply"){
        $name = $PRAT['dictionary_entry'];
        $unit = "";
        unset($values);
            foreach ($PRAT->VALUE as $VALUE) {
                $values[] = (string)$VALUE . $VALUE['unit'];
                };
        $statsarray[(string)$name] = implode(array_filter($values),"|");
        }
    };

    //Compare against headers
    $statsarray = str_replace(",",".",$statsarray);
    $spreadsheetarray = array_fill(0, count($headerarray),"");
    foreach ($statsarray as $description=>$value) {
        $spreadsheetarray[array_search($description,$headerarray)]=$value;
    };
    foreach ($spreadsheetarray as $description=> $value) {
        $spreadsheetarray[$description] = str_replace(',','.',$value);
        //add column for woocommerce display
        //$spreadsheetarray[$description] = ",".$value;
    };
    echo (implode($spreadsheetarray,","));
    echo "<BR>";
    unset($statsarray);
    unset($spreadsheetarray);
    };
echo "</span>";
//End XML if
};
?>
```

This is what i managed to do..It Outputs a single csv with along with empty values when i view it in browser. All headers along with its values(including empty values are printed here)
I dont know how to avoid empty values and its headers and put it in a product specific csv.

Comment: since you haven't started coding, you can use `simplexml_load_file` to parse your XML, then start off by building the array then finally using it on `fputcsv()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to following and it worked for me.

```
 foreach ($product->COLL as $COLL) {
    foreach ($COLL->PRAT as $PRAT){
        if($COLL['attrtype']=="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply"){
        $headerarray[] =  $COLL['dictionary_entry'];
        }
    };
    };
    foreach ($product->PRAT as $PRAT) {
    if($PRAT['attrtype']=="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply"){
    $headerarray[] =  $PRAT['dictionary_entry'];
    }
    };

    //echo "ID,";
    $headerarray = array_values(array_unique($headerarray));

    foreach ($product->COLL as $COLL) {
        if($COLL['attrtype']=="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply"){
        $name = $COLL['dictionary_entry'];
        $unit = "";
        unset($values);
        foreach ($COLL->PRAT as $PRAT){
            foreach ($PRAT->VALUE as $VALUE) {
                    if(!empty($name)) {
                    $values[] = (string)$VALUE.$VALUE['unit'];
                    }
                };
            };
        $statsarray[(string)$name] = $name." ".implode(array_filter($values),"|");
        }
    };
    foreach ($product->PRAT as $PRAT) {
        if($PRAT['attrtype']=="ProductattributeTypeScopeSupply"){
        $name = $PRAT['dictionary_entry'];
        $unit = "";
        unset($values);
            foreach ($PRAT->VALUE as $VALUE) {
                    if(!empty($name)){
                    $values[] = $name." ". (string)$VALUE .$VALUE['unit'];
                    }
                };
        $statsarray[(string)$name] = implode(array_filter($values),"|");
        }
    };
    $statsarray = str_replace(",",".",$statsarray);

    foreach ($statsarray as $description=>$value) {
        $spreadsheetarray[array_search($description,$headerarray)]=$value;

    };
    foreach ($spreadsheetarray as $description=> $value) {
        $spreadsheetarray[$description] = str_replace(',','.',$value);

    };
```